# How do I respond on a form to events being triggered in a class?

Tags: c#, events, eventargs

I'm going through my code and redoing all my events so they are in compliance with [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182133.aspx) but I've run into a wall. Here's my code:

**Script.cs**

```
public EventHandler<ScriptEvent> Load;

protected virtual void OnLoad(string file)
{
    EventHandler<ScriptEvent> handler = Load;

    if(Load != null)
       Load(this, new ScriptEvent(file));
}
```

and ScriptEvent:

**ScriptEvents.cs**

```
public class ScriptEvent : EventArgs
{
    private string m_File;

    public string File
    {
        get { return m_File; }
    }        

    public ScriptEvent(string file)
    {
       this.m_File = file;
    }
}
```

The problem is I cannot figure out how to make it so my form can handle the events. For instance, a file is loaded inside of Script.cs, then the form displays the file when OnLoad(...) inside of Script.cs is called. if that's confusing:

1) Script.cs loads a file and triggers OnLoad(file)

2) Form1 picks up on OnLoad and does whatever.

I figured it would be something similar to the way I was going it before (script.OnLoad += script_OnLoad(...)) but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want:

```
script.Load += script_OnLoad;
```

This will add your handler to the event. Then when the `OnLoad` method is called, it will invoke your handler.

Your script_OnLoad method needs to look like this:

```
void script_OnLoad(object sender, ScriptEvent args)
{
     // your code here - you can get the file name out of the args.File
}
```

Your Script.cs can be cut down to:

```
public EventHandler<ScriptEvent> Load;

protected virtual void OnLoad(string file)
{
    if(Load != null)
        Load(this, new ScriptEvent(file));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now. I think was thrown off because script_OnLoad(...) wasn't automatically generated when I did script.Load += ..., can't believe it was that simple. I've been spoiled by auto complete. Thanks again!